# Add comma between values by using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, split, string-concatenation

My values come from ComboBox:

> 2|722|742|762|77

I delete unnecessary characters as follows:

```
foreach (var item in checkListBox)
{
    string[] list = item.Split(
        new string[] { "2|" },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

My list values result:

```
"72"
"74"
"76"
"77"
```

My question is:

how can I get all of the above values in **1 row** (next to each other) separated by **comma** like this:

> 72,74,76,77

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
var result = string.Join(",", item.Split(new string[] { "2|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you just want [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx):

```
string commaSeparated = string.Join(",", list);
```

(Note that this is not part of LINQ - it's not the same kind of "join" as for joining multiple sequences. It's joining several strings together with a separator.)

While you *can* do this in a single statement as per the currently accepted answer, I'd personally consider leaving your existing statement and having this as a separate step. It makes the code easier to both read and debug.

Answer (score 3):

```
String.Join(",",list);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Though: a) This is not Linq. b) As is mentioned in another answer here - It would be simpler in this case to use `Replace`.

Using Linq:

```
list.Select(s => s + ",").Aggregate((s, q) => s + q).TrimEnd(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Replace` directly:

```
string input = "2|722|742|762|77";
var result = input.Replace("2|",",").Trim(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the other answers, `string.Join` is what should be used here. If you'd however insist on LINQ:

```
var result = list
    .Skip(1)
    .Aggregate(
        list.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty,
        (total, current) => total + "," + current);
```